# What is the purpose of WINRT_NOT_PRESENT?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In a few Windows 8 App code samples I've seen code blocks encapsulated by these preprocessor instructions

```
#if !WINRT_NOT_PRESENT
#endif
```

Is WinRT not *always* present in Windows 8 Store apps?

Comment: It's likely just used for writing portable code in portable libraries, for example.

Comment: If I had to guess... samples for WP7+WP8 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is used by Microsoft's NotificationsExtensions library. You need to specify this build symbol if you want to use ASP.NET to send push notifications to Windows Push Notification Services (WNS).

From [Quickstart: Using the NotificationsExtensions library in your code (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh969156.aspx):

> You can also use NotificationsExtensions in your app server code if you are using ASP.NET to send push notifications to Windows Push Notification Services (WNS). The only caveat is that you must add the WINRT_NOT_PRESENT compilation build symbol in the NotificationsExtensions project properties.